# физические величины и единицы измерения в C#

Tags: c#

Помогите с реализацией работы с физическими величинами в С#. 
В математических пакетах таких как Mathematica и MathCad есть достаточно удобная работа с физическими величинами: Если задать переменные с размерностью, то результат вычисления будет с приведенной размерностью в системе СИ. Есть ли какая либо библиотека с возможностью делать подобное в C#?

Comment: https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet, https://github.com/cureos/csunits

Comment: Спасибо! отличные библиотеки! Решил попробовать UnitsNet как более обширную.